# перебор массива со 2-ого элемента smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Добрый день народ нужен совет, 
есть массив:

```
   $arr = array(0 => 'Tennis', 1 => 'Swimming', 2 => 'Coding', 3 => 'Poding');
   $iaView->assign('myArray', $arr);
```

в шаблоне вывод:

```
{foreach $myArray as $key => $value}
  <li>{$value}</li>
{/foreach}
```

никак не могу понять как начать перебор массива со 2-ого элемента, возможно кто уже сталкивался с данным вопросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В smarty есть возможность фильтровать значения переменных. Причем фильтром может быть любая функция PHP. Например [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

```
{foreach $myArray|array_slice:1 as $key => $value}
    <li>{$value}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помог Ваше ответ...! Все получилось как раз как было запланировано.